# How can we conditionally run a delete query in a transaction with other queries

Tags: sql, transactions, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

I have a few queries in a transaction.
There is a condition when a new column is added, I need to run a delete query for the same.

The variable `new_column_added` is indicative of whether a new column has been added or not. How can I conditionally run the `delete query` only when the value is true?

E.g.

```
begin;

{some delete query to be executed only when the value for <new_column_added> is true}

{some inserts}

{some updates}

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `new_column_added` variable exists within the same scope/block and has a value that is ready-to-use, using MySQL syntax (other database systems will have slightly different structures), the delete part will look like below:

```
IF (new_column_added) THEN
  { some delete query to be executed only when the value for <new_column_added> is true };
END IF;
```

Amazon Redshift seems to have similar syntax according to this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-conditionals-if